# Asp.Net multiple AuthenticationSchemas - User doesn't get redirected to LoginPath Uri

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, asp.net-mvc-5, jwt

I'm trying to set up an `ASP.Net 5` web project with `JWTBearer authentication` for API Controllers *(Controllers decorated with the APIController attribute)* and `CookieAuthentication` for MVC Controllers *(Controller classes derived from Controller, to render Views)*. The relevant part of my `ConfigureServices` method in the `Startup` Class looks like this:

```
services
    .AddAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    })
    .AddJwtBearer(options =>
    {
        options.SaveToken = true;
        options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
            IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("My Secret Key")),
            ValidateAudience = false,
            ValidateIssuer = false,
            RequireExpirationTime = false,
            ValidateLifetime = true
        };
    })
    .AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
    {
        options.LoginPath = "/account/login";
        options.LogoutPath = "/account/logout";
        options.AccessDeniedPath = "/account/accessdenied";
        options.Cookie = new CookieBuilder {SameSite = SameSiteMode.Strict};
        options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20);
    });

var schemePolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder(
        CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
        JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
    .Build();

services.AddAuthorization(o => o.DefaultPolicy = schemePolicy);
```

In an MCV Controller I have an `Action` like the below:

```
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
public IActionResult AnActionForAuthenticatedUsers()
{
    //  do some stuff...
    return View();
}
```

Now I would expect that when an unauthenticated request for this action comes in the request will be forwarded to **/account/login** but it is not. Instead a `401 statuscode` is returned.

The webserver says:

```
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.DefaultAuthorizationService[2]
      Authorization failed. These requirements were not met:
      DenyAnonymousAuthorizationRequirement: Requires an authenticated user.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationHandler[12]
      AuthenticationScheme: Cookies was challenged.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler[12]
      AuthenticationScheme: Bearer was challenged.
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: I'm not fully sure but I think cookies scheme can't be used for Challenge. You need to forward authentication challenge to JWT scheme. Check [`ForwardChallenge`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.authenticationschemeoptions.forwardchallenge?view=aspnetcore-5.0#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Authentication_AuthenticationSchemeOptions_ForwardChallenge) option

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is not in Authentication policy, but in Authorization configuration
Create a separate policy for each type of Authorization and that would work as you are expecting:

```
services.AddAuthorization(o =>
{
    o.AddPolicy(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, schemePolicy);
    o.AddPolicy(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, schemePolicy);
});
```